# Tensorflow random distribution from tensor layer

Tags: python, arrays, random, tensorflow, dimension

I have a 4D array, and I am trying to select from this array all of the first three dimensions and then a random distribution of the fourth dimension

```
samples = np.unique( np.random.randint(subset_start, subset_end, size=50) )    
layer_tensor = model.layer_tensors[model_layer][:, :, :, samples]
```

Which gives me:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1
    **From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [], [], [], [44].**
```

where

```
model.layer_tensors[model_layer].shape == (?,?,?,1024)
```

previously, I was selecting a continuous range of values where

```
model.layer_tensors[model_layer][:, :, :, subset_start:subset_end]
```

is a valid statement

Comment: Are you using tensorflow without adding the very relevant tensorflow-tag (while spamming *sample* which does not help at all)? Also: a more complete (best-case: reproducable) code would be nice.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) might help.

```
layer_tensor = tf.gather(model.layer_tensors[model_layer], samples, axis=-1)
```

Though you should consider generating the samples as a tensor.

Comment: You should accept the answer then. It helps people identify what worked when they face something similar